# Ubuntu 20.04 Gem::LoadError when trying mastodon db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-20.04, mastodon

The error:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 13.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 13.0.6.
```

The command run:

```
docker-compose run --rm web rake db:migrate
```

Running this command on my ~/mastodon folder results in the above error.

Countless solutions involving running gem uninstall on various folders, assorted methods of updating, each throwing their own errors. Multiple ruby on rails managers, no luck. I hope one of you can help me get this command to run safely

Comment: use `bundle exec rake` instead of just `rake`

Comment: @arieljuod So THAT's where the bundle exec is supposed to go. Most unhelpful error ever. That worked, obviously. Post that as an answer so I can approve it and close this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `bundle exec rake` instead of just `rake` in the command

EDIT: you can probably do `docker-compose run --rm web rails db:migrate` instead since it runs bundle internally too but it depends on the rails version